# How to create a React Component from a String

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to resolve the following module from memory by downloading it as a String then storing it as a file in memory:

**testRemote.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TestRemote extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (<div>HELLO WORLD!</div>);
    }
}  

export default TestRemote;
```

**Download it:**

```
let myModuleString = response = await fetch(module_url).text();
```

**Get the Component object:**

```
let TestRemote = await import('data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + myModuleString);
```

Is there a way I could achieve the intended outcome?

The above attempt throws the error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'data:text' in '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs'
```

Comment: You can only import a module at the topmost scope of the module file.

Comment: Why not save it to a file and then import it?

Comment: @utkarsh-dixit How can I go about saving it to a file in Javascript?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought you were using SSR here